# python multiprocessing not working?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def seq(count):
    print "runing seq"
    start_time = time.time()
    result = []
    for i in range(count):
        result.append(cube(i))
    print "seq --- time:{0:.4f}".format(time.time() - start_time)
    #print "seq --- time:{0:.4f}, result:{1}".format(time.time() - start_time, result)

def par(count):
    print "runing par"
    start_time = time.time()
    result = mp.Pool(processes=2).map(cube,range(count))
    print "par --- time:{0:.4f}".format(time.time() - start_time)
    #print "par --- time:{0:.4f}, result:{1}".format(time.time() - start_time, result)

def cube(x):
    return x*x*x


count = 4000000
seq(count)
par(count)
```

Output:

> seq --- time:1.7011
>
> par --- time:2.3112

My mac has one processor, two physical cores, and 2 virtual cores for each physical core. So, I figured it should be fine running in parallel to gain some speedup. However, from the output, it showed that parallel version is slower than the sequential version. Why is this the case?

spec:

[image: spec]
[image: 4 virtual cores]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the operation you're parallelizing isn't very expensive, which negates the benefits of `multiprocessing`. Using `multiprocessing` carries some overhead; starting up child processes and moving data from your parent process to those children takes a non-trivial amount of time (especially compared to a threaded solution). If the actual work you're doing in the background processes is very small, the overhead of moving the data between processes can actually end up being greater than the amount of time you save by parallelizing the work.

You can see this more clearly if you add a short `time.sleep` into your test code (and reduce the number of runs, so you're not waiting around forever):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def seq(count):
    print "runing seq"
    start_time = time.time()
    result = []
    for i in range(count):
        result.append(cube(i))
    print "seq --- time:{0:.4f}".format(time.time() - start_time)
    #print "seq --- time:{0:.4f}, result:{1}".format(time.time() - start_time, result)

def par(count):
    print "runing par"
    start_time = time.time()
    result = mp.Pool(processes=2).map(cube,range(count))
    print "par --- time:{0:.4f}".format(time.time() - start_time)
    #print "par --- time:{0:.4f}, result:{1}".format(time.time() - start_time, result)

def cube(x):
    time.sleep(.01)
    return x*x*x

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    count = 400
    seq(count)
    par(count)
```

Output:

```
runing seq
seq --- time:4.0488
runing par
par --- time:2.0408
```

The additional time spent inside of `cube` makes the parallel version twice as fast the sequential one, which is right about the expected performance improvement.

Comment: One thing worth mentioning is that `multiprocessing` requires that the `__main__` module be importable by the children (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html), so the calls to `seq` and `par` would need to be protected by an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

Comment: @Nathaniel That's only required on Windows, but definitely worth pointing out for other folks who see this. I've updated my answer accordingly.